# Carbocation formation and stability from bromo compounds

Tags: stability, resonance, carbocation, hyperconjugation, inductive-effect

> When heated,the following bromo-species all form carbocations via $\sigma$ bond cleavage. For each structure draw the corresponding carbocation and briefly describe how it is stabilised.
> [image: Question]

This is my attempt at answering the question:
[image: My solution]

I would like to know whether I have drawn the correct carbocation forms of each of these bromo-compounds and if my reasoning is sound.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both your answers and reasoning are correct. For the second compound a slight ambiguity might arise, because the $\mathrm{sp^2}$-hybridized carbons show $\text{-I}$ effect which would destabilize the carbocation, however considering the fact that there are not only  $\ce{2 Me}$— groups attached which show $\text{+I}$, they are also closer than one of the $\mathrm{sp^2}$- carbons, it is quite natural that the net inductive effect would stabilize it.